# Find a Lipschitz constant w.r.t. y of $f(x,y)=(e^y-1)^\frac{2}{3}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the Lipschitz constant with respect to y of the function

$f : [-1,1] \times [-2,0], \qquad (x,y) \mapsto (e^y-1)^\frac{2}{3}$

$|f(x,y_1) - f(x,y_2)| =|(e^{y_1}-1)^\frac{2}{3}-(e^{y_2}-1)^\frac{2}{3}|\leq$

I know $\forall x\in [-1,1] , \forall y\in [-2,0]$ exist $(e^y-1)^\frac{2}{3}>0 $

Here I got stuck, how am I supposes to simplify this expression? Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: Use Mean value Theorem.

Comment: Close to zero, $e^y-1$ behaves like $y$, and $y^{2/3}$ is not Lipschitz at $y=0$. It would be surprising (but not impossible until proven so) if you could find a Lipschitz constant.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thank you !
Since $lim_{y\to0}\space y=lim_{y\to0}\space (e^y-1)=0$.

It sufficient to show $\forall k\in \mathbb R \space \exists y\in[-2,0] \space \space |y_1^{\frac{2}{3}}-y_2^{\frac{2}{3}}|>k|y_1-y_2|$?
I tried to get a contradiction:
If exists $k\in \mathbb R $ such that $\forall y\in[-2,0]$ exists $|y_1^{\frac{2}{3}}-y_2^{\frac{2}{3}}|<k|y_1-y_2|$$ , How can I continue please ?

Comment: As was said, using the mean value theorem. Or use the binomial formula for cubics, $A^3-B^3=(A-B)(A^2+AB+B^2)$.